# Select name from drop down box to show both picture and name

Tags: android, spinner

Does anyone know how do i implement a way in android studios such that when i select a name from the spinner, both the name and a picture of the guy will appear?

Something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ask2K.png

Comment: you need to use a custom layout

Answer (score 0):

Like Omid said, you have to create a custom layout. I have found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO5F0nnzAw) explaining how to do this.

Hope this helps,

Owen